# How to use regex to remove semi colons?

Tags: regex, notepad++, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

Hello I have this kind of data :

```
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
a;g;h;j
f;g;f;d
a;d;8;d
```

And I would like to modify to have this :

```
a;bc;d
1;23;4
a;gh;j
f;gf;d
a;d8;d
```

Obviously I have a lot of lines but every time the semi colons are in the same position. I tried to select the columns with notepad++ and to to replace the semi colon by nothing but the box is grey...

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Hold ALT+SHIFT and use the arrow keys to select second semicolon and delete it.

OR

Hold ALT and click and drag the mouse to select a second semicolon and delete it.

OR

- Find : `^(...)(.)`
- Replace with: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an online regex tester that i did the work on, you can just replace your data with the samples.

```
Regex : (\w+;)((\w+);(\w+))(;\w+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5GCdrw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^;]+;[^;]+\K;`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of string
  [^;]+     # 1 or more non semicolon
  ;         # 1 semi colon
  [^;]+     # 1 or more non semicolon
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  ;         # 1 semi colon
```

**Result for given example:**

```
a;bc;d
1;23;4
a;gh;j
f;gf;d
a;d8;d
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the possible values of the data are lowercase characters a-z or a digit you could also capture the first 3 characters using a capturing group and a character class `[a-z0-9]` and after that match a semicolon. If there can be more than 1 character you could use a quantifier `+` for the character class like `[a-z0-9]+`

Then replace with the first capturing group.

**Find what**

`^([a-z0-9];[a-z0-9]);`

**Replace with**

`$1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhlwZP/1)

Or Using `\K` you could find `^[a-z0-9];[a-z0-9]\K;` and leave Replace with empty.